# Check there is one checked checkbox before display confirm dialog Wicket

Tags: java, javascript, validation, checkbox, wicket

I intended to give user a chance to confirm their action by adding JavascriptEventConfirmation as the example from this tutorial :

https://cwiki.apache.org/WICKET/getting-user-confirmation.html

However, I want to be able to check first if there is at least one checkbox (out of mulitple) is being checked before displaying the confirmation dialog.

How can I achieve this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Note that the confirmation is implemented via a simple javascript snippet that is added to the button tag's `onclick` attribute.

To add the verification, just change the generated snippet to fit your needs.